# Create Snapshot of FS from Spark Job

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, java

I would like to create a snapshot of the underlying HDFS, when running a spark job. The particular step involves deleting contents of some parquet files.  I want to create a snapshot  perform the delete operation, verify  the operation results and   proceed with next Steps.

However, I am unable to find a good way to access the HDFS API from my spark job. The directory I want to create a snapshot is tagged/marked snapshotable in HDFS.  the command line  method of creating the snapshot works, However I need to do this programmatically.

i am running Spark 1.5 on CDH 5.5.

any hints clues as to how I can perform this operation ?

Thanks

Ramdev

Comment: I don't know the specific syntax for Java (Runtime.getRuntime().exec???) but you could run system commands from your code that would allow you to use HDFS commands which you could then interact with via the standard input and output variables.

Comment: @Salmonerd  there is a java API to create snapshots. however that required access to the the HDFS api. I am not sure I get that access from a Spark Context to the HDFS directly. Most examples have an embedded hadoop clusters created to access the HDFS apis.

Comment: What I am saying is that you can access HDFS by writing HDFS commands in your Java code instead of accessing any APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not verified this, but atleast I do not get Compile errors and in theory this solution should work.

This is scala code:

```
val sc = new SparkContext();
val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfig)
val snapshotPath = fs.createSnapshot("path to createsnapshot of","snapshot name")

.....
.....
if (condition satisfied) {
  fs.deleteSnapshot(snapshotPath,"snapshot name")
}
```

I assume this will work in theory.